# Keycloak-js updateToken(minValidity) needs clarifications

Tags: javascript, typescript, token, keycloak

I read many examples of the method in Keycloak-js without a clear explanation of the following method.

```
        updateToken(minValidity: number): KeycloakPromise<boolean, boolean>;
```

Note : I am using `"keycloak-js": "^15.0.2"`

Here is its documentation

````
    /**
     * If the token expires within `minValidity` seconds, the token is refreshed.
     * If the session status iframe is enabled, the session status is also
     * checked.
     * @returns A promise to set functions that can be invoked if the token is
     *          still valid, or if the token is no longer valid.
     * @example
     * ```js
     * keycloak.updateToken(5).then(function(refreshed) {
     *   if (refreshed) {
     *     alert('Token was successfully refreshed');
     *   } else {
     *     alert('Token is still valid');
     *   }
     * }).catch(function() {
     *   alert('Failed to refresh the token, or the session has expired');
     * });
     */
````

I am not a native english speaker. The term "expires within" is imprecise here.

An illustration is better understood. This method `updateToken` periodically checks if the token is expired or not during a window of time `minValidity`

[image]

**When the token will be refreshed ?**

When the keycloak token expiration is approaching, the token refreshment is either :

- right prior its expiration date within the window of time `minValidity` ( blue)
- OR after the next period update check. (orange)

In the blue case, it makes sense to have a large enough value of `minValidity`.

In the orange case, a small value is better.

I understand it is the blue case.

Bonus question :  **What will happen if the token duration < minValidity ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overall you want to avoid a situation where you send the AccessToken to a server/service and it gets rejected because it's not valid anymore.

So it's a good idea to check validity everytime before using the token. As the documentation mentions: calls to a service/backend should only be made within the callback of the `updateToken` method. But beside that, there is no (automatic) periodic check for refreshing the token.

The `minValidity` comes into place if you imagine a situation where the remaining AccessToken Lifetime is only 1 second.
If you check the token on client side (`isTokenExpired()` => `false`) it will still be valid, but there is a probability, that when the request reaches a service, the token will not be valid anymore and gets rejected.  => we want to avoid that

The default value for `minValidity` is 5 seconds. So when calling the `updateToken` method and the token is still valid, but will expire within the next 5 seconds the token gets refreshed and any service/backend call inside the callback will use the new token. But a call itself does not necessarily mean a new token. If the remaining lifetime is long enough, nothing happens.

So in your example the blue situation is correct. The second "update" call (if you mean a `updateToken` method call) will already trigger a token refresh. But again: The update calls are not done automatically. You need to either implement a periodic check or call updateToken before a backend call.

To your bonus question: I looked into the code and in a fictional situation where e.g. minValidity is 60s but a new fresh token is always only valid for 30s, a call to updateToken will trigger a refresh everytime. But imho there will be no recurring "refresh-loop"

Comment: Thanks, my thought on blue case. Thanks on the bonus question if token duration < minValidity , then `updateToken` will trigger a refresh everytime.